# How to preserve a SQLite database from being reverted after deploying to OpenShift?

Tags: python, sqlite, openshift

I ported a Python Twisted application to OpenShift, which stores its data to a SQLite database. After putting database file to the git repo `data/` directory (during the first deploy) I had no issues, but the database was simply resetted at the second deploy.

I searched for a proper solution to this weird behavior (considering that the database was under versioning) and then I found  [the answer in the OpenShift Knowledge Base](https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1002/deploying-openshift-express-applications-using-sqlite):

> The short solution to this issue is to store your SQLite database **one level up from your git repository in the ‘data’ directory**.

Now my question is what happens when I move the database to this directory? Have I to move or copy the data directory's content? And this data will be preserver from deploy to deploy?

I tried to move the database from `repo/data` to `data/` directory but the application cannot access this upper level directory. I'm looking for the best solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution by dividing my application data into two categories:

- stateful data
- dynamic data

I left the stateful information in the `repo/data` directory and I moved permanently the changing data to the upper level `data/` directory. Making this change I am able to maintain the stateful_data under version control in my git repo accessing them through:

```
 __location__ = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))
 static_data_folder = __location__ + '/data/'
```

The dynamically generated data is then moved to `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` which is NOT under version control and corresponds to the upper level directory of my `app-root`. I changed my getter in my singleton Configuration module to return this *mutable data folder*:

```
self.mutable_data_path = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'] + "mutable_data_subdir/"
```

I'm testing this configuration right now but it seems to work like a charm.